# Migrating Event System from 5.3 to 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, publishing, event-system, upgrade, 5.3

We are currently in the process of upgrading from Tridion R5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

One of the parts to upgrade is the event system which we will also be migrating from VB to .NET (C#).

During the upgrade, we are experiencing problems regarding the events "Component - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed" and "Page - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed". 
In R5.3 SP1, the corresponding events "ComponentTemplate - SetPublishedTo - Post" and "Page - SetPublishedTo - Post" are fired each time a component or page is published or unpublished.

In 2011 SP1 however, sometimes an event is received, sometimes not. The events seem to be firing at random from our point of view. In the Tridion event logs, there is no error message to be found. The same goes for any log file.

Therefor we would like to know

- Are the Tridion 2011 SP1 events "Component - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed" and "Page - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed", the replacements of Tridion 5.3 events "ComponentTemplate - SetPublishedTo - Post" and "Page - SetPublishedTo - Post"?
- When should the events "Component - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed" and "Page - SetPublishStateEventArgs - EventPhase.Processed" be fired in Tridion 2011 SP1?
- If the events correspond and if the behavior of the events is the same as R5.3 SP1, what are we doing wrong?

So in short - we want to fire an event after the publish transaction of a DCP has been committed by the deployer.

Thanks

Comment: Bart Koopman has a nice event matrix here:  http://sdltridionworld.com/images/event_matrix_tcm89-18738.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

issue identified: there was an extra Tridion box in the development environment installed (for the sake of testing the roll-out procedure), that shared the same database. The server/publisher service was still running, and was picking (randomly, of course) publishing actions from the other CMS box. We disabled the publisher of the second box, and issue was solved.

Comment: Randomness is rarely random...

Answer (score 6):

First of all you should subscribe to `TransactionComitted` phase - this is the phase in which you can be sure that operation succeeded. I have just checked it on my system and it is working like a charm. I suspect the problem is that your component has no corresponding dynamic component template and is not actually published, so no event triggered.

I don't know what your requirements are, but you may also consider subscribing to PublishTransaction Save event.

Comment: A big difference between PublishTransaction - Save and the events mentioned above is that PublishTransaction - Save is called once, while the events above fire for each resolved page or component of the publishtransaction.

Comment: Actually, PublishTransactionSave is triggered every time its status is changing, so plenty of times